# Is it possible to highlight (not select) multiple rows in QListWidget?? (Python/PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I was wondering if it was possible to **highlight** multiple rows in a `QListWidget` (not `setSelectedRow` or select multiple rows)...And if so, how would i go about doing that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to highlight the items in a listWidget. You can set the background color, foreground color or completely change the font of the items to be highlighted.

Set the foreground:

```
for item in listWidget.selectedItems():
    item.setForeground(QBrush(Qt.green, Qt.SolidPattern))
```

Set the background:

```
for item in listWidget.selectedItems():
    item.setBackground(QBrush(Qt.yellow, Qt.SolidPattern))
```

Or change the font of the items:

```
font = QFont('', -1, QFont.Bold, True)
for item in listWidget.selectedItems():
    item.setFont(font)
```

Empty string to QFont means default font family, -1 means default font size, finally made the font **bold** and made it *italic* by setting the last parameter to True. If you don't want **bold** font, pass -1 instead of `QFont.Bold`

Comment: How do I return it to the default color?